# How to Calculate Application Level Data Usage in windows

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, winapi

I wanted some way to calculate data usage of each application running in windows OS separately.
I want to achieve something similar to inbuilt data usage of windows.

[image: link]

After doing some research I came to know that windows do in some way and store in DB file("SRUDB.dat") located at this location "C:\Windows\System32\sru"
If I will be able to read this DB somehow that will be also enough to full fill my purpose.

Comment: So what happened when you looked at that file?

Comment: Why don't you just use GetProcessMemoryInfo()? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo

Comment: The file is in .dat extension I already tried to read it using notepad and db readers, non of them worked. @bommelding

Comment: Read this pdf file : https://www.sans.org/summit-archives/file/summit-archive-1492184583.pdf 

also this opensource project help you to read the database : https://github.com/libyal/libesedb

Comment: There are too many tags (*C*, *C++*, *C#*). Pick one.

Comment: You forgot to tag Java, Visual Basic, F, Fortran and Ada.

Comment: As in windows platform many times it is not possible to achieve many things using c# language because windows it self written in (c & c++) language.That' s why added all three language as tags. @CristiFati

Comment: Thanks @MojtabaTajik --- Is there any other way to calculate by own of each application by making some service?
It can be achieved if I install WinPCap driver and sniff packets at network layer. 
But I don't want to install any external driver in the system.

Comment: @AnandKishore you can generate DLL file that hook the network APIs for x86 and x64 process and inject the DLL to processes that you want to monitor.
The previous versions of DUMeter do this to measure network IO of running process but i don't know this case goes on or on.